# Get value from <block> in page.xml

Tags: magento

I need to use the same custom made block 2 times on the same page but with different values loaded from the database.

So I need to transfer a config value(Here called SimpleMenuInstanceRef) from my page.xml file to the block/model so each block knows what data to load from the database.

I am doing it with this block:

```
    <block template="simplemenu/leftMenuTemplate.phtml" type="simplemenu/standard" name="leftMenu" as="leftMenu" translate="label">
        <label>Left menu header</label>
        <action method="setSimpleMenuInstanceRef"><SimpleMenuInstanceRef>4</SimpleMenuInstanceRef></action>
        </block>
```

And this kinda works. In my leftMenuTemplate.phtml I can do a

echo $this->getSimpleMenuInstanceRef()

And this will show the value from the config.

But I need the value in my blocks _construct method so I can load data depending on its value. But doing a $this->getSimpleMenuInstanceRef in _construct don't return anything. So how can I get the value in my block code, or do I need to transfer the value in an other way?

Edit: Changed __construct to _construct to match real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need. Try to declare block as:

```
<block instance="4" template="simplemenu/leftMenuTemplate.phtml" type="simplemenu/standard" name="leftMenu" as="leftMenu" translate="label">
    <label>Left menu header</label>
</block>
```

After doing this, you can easily access to the 'instance' var:

```
protected function _construct() {
    parent::_construct();
    echo $this->getData('instance');
}
```

Comment: That don't work. At least not in the block __construct method. $this->getData("instance") just return null. And if I call $this->getData() I get an array with just a single value(Which is not the name/value pair I need.

Comment: never use __construct, use _construct instead

Comment: Sorry. I do use _construct I just made an _ to much in the text.

Comment: oh, i was wrong. seems like there's no other way to transfer a config value to the block. And if you need to load your data, you can easily load it in `_prepareLayout` method

Comment: What do you mean with "No other way"? Do you mean that the correct/only way to do it is to let the view(leftMenuTemplate.phtml) call a method on the block with the value?

Comment: yea, i mean that the magento way is to use `action` xml tag

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** Despite the `createBlock` functions (in `Mage_Core_Mode_Layout`) having paramaters for an `$arguments` array, it turns out the block constructor (in modern version of Magento) doesn't pass the attributes through

```
$block = $this->addBlock($className, $blockName);

...

public function addBlock($block, $blockName)
{
    return $this->createBlock($block, $blockName);
}

...

public function createBlock($type, $name='', array $attributes = array())
{
    ...
    $block = $this->_getBlockInstance($type, $attributes);
    ...
}
```

So the core of this answer is incorrect. I'm leaving the answer here though, as it contains other useful information.

Here's the problem with that you're trying to do.

Each node of the Layout XML represents a line of PHP code that's used to generate your block.

When you say

```
<block template="simplemenu/leftMenuTemplate.phtml"
```

what happens behind the scenes looks like this (where `$attributes` is a representation of the node's attributes)

```
$block = new $block($attributes);
```

Then, Magento encounters your next line

```
<action method="setSimpleMenuInstanceRef"><SimpleMenuInstanceRef>4</SimpleMenuInstanceRef></action>
```

which is translated as

```
$block->setSimpleMenuInstanceRef('4');
```

So, the problem you're running into is when the `__construct`, `_construct`, and `_prepareLayout` methods are called, Magento hasn't processed the `action` node, so your value isn't set.

One possible solution is to include your data as the block's attribute (`my_data_here` below)

```
<block template="simplemenu/leftMenuTemplate.phtml" type="simplemenu/standard" name="leftMenu" as="leftMenu" translate="label" my_data_here="4">
```

The attributes are passed into the block's constructor method.  While the base block doesn't have a `__construct`, the `Varien_Object` class it extends does

```
#File: lib/Varien/Object.php
public function __construct()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    if (empty($args[0])) {
        $args[0] = array();
    }
    $this->_data = $args[0];

    $this->_construct();
}
```

This constructor will take the first constructor argument and set it as the object's (in this case, the object is our block) data array.  This means you can pull that data back out with

```
$this->getMyDataHere();
$this->getData('my_data_here');
//...
```

One caveat.

If you want to do this you can't create your own constructor method in your block, because that means the Varien_Object constructor will never be called.  That's why you want to use the single underscore constructor (_construct) in all your blocks.

I wrote an article a while back that covers all the [event lifecycle methods](http://alanstorm.com/magneto_listener_lifecycle_block), you may find it useful